# Why do I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I'm getting a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` for this code:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 10, 11], [5, 6, 7]]

b = list(zip(*a))

total = 0

for i in len(b):
    for j in len(i):
        total += b[i][j]
    total = total/len(b[i])
b[i] = total
```

I am trying to get the sum of each tuple in the list and should end up with a list something like: `[9, 18, 21]`.

Why am I getting this error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` when I run the code?

Comment: `for i in len(b):` is trying to iterate the number returned by `len`. `for i in 3` doesn't make sense. I think you mean `for i in range(len(b)):`.

Comment: FWIW, `[sum(t) for t in zip(*a)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 10, 11], [5, 6, 7]]
b = list(zip(*a))
new_list = []
for i in b:
    total = 0 
    for j in i:
        total+=j
    new_list.append(total)

print(new_list)
```